# Parsing JSON with Javascript/jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, json

I'm having trouble with embedding json in my website.

This is html and javascript:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="us">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Example Page</title>
    <link href="css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.js"></script>
    <script>

    function isJSON(str) {
        try {
            JSON.parse(str)
        } catch (e) {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }

    jQuery(function(){

        <?
            $arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
        ?>

        data = <?= json_encode($arr) ?>

        if (isJSON(data)) {
            json = jQuery.parseJSON(data)
            console.log(json)
        } else {
            console.log("Not a json.")
            console.log(data)
            console.log(jQuery.parseJSON(data))
        }

    })


    </script>

<body>


</body>
</html>
```

This outputs in console the following:

```
Not a json. filename.php:29
Object {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5} filename.php:30
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
```

Been a long day already and most probably (hopefully) I'm missing something obvious.
I tried validate the generated json here: http://jsonlint.com/ and according to their site it was valid.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Avoid using PHP short tags.

Comment: @BenM Why? - I've never had problems with them.

Comment: @krabats: They're not enabled by default on all servers.

Comment: Portability, as @cdmckay indicated. Much safer to use `<?php echo ... ?>`

Comment: @BenM thanks for caring to point this out but this is plain wrong. Been working with many servers and never had problems with short tags not being enabled. And on top of that: http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php since php 5.4.0 short echo is now official part of php regardless of php.ini configuration.

Comment: Good for you. There are still servers out there that won't support this. Until they're no more, err on the side of caution.

Comment: @krabats: I've had issues where a client's host didn't have short tags turned on.  Any code that you write pre-5.4.0 should not use short tags unless you know for sure you'll always have control of the server's PHP settings.

Comment: @cdmckay I think most modern servers have this option enabled or at least they allow users to control it. I guess I'll stick with the shorter version still cause it's just too damn handy comparing to longer version. And if I'll run into issue where I have no control over it and stubborn hosting admins won't enable it - I'll just do search&replace. Thanks for the answer tho.

Comment: +1 to all answers. Thanks for helping me out (or trying at least) in these dark debugging times!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON is (more or less) a JavaScript literal.

If you dump it into a script, you don't need to parse it at all.

```
var data = <?php echo json_encode($arr); ?>;
console.log(data);
```

If you want something to pass to `jQuery.parseJSON` then you need to generate a JavaScript string containing JSON, not plain JSON.

Comment: In case it's not clear, after PHP runs the first line will look like `var data = {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}`.  If you view source you should see that now.

Comment: The issue was in a different piece of code but your post pushed me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues I see here (in addition to using PHP short tags).  First, you're missing semicolons at the end of all lines.  And second is in line

```
data = <?= json_encode($arr) ?>;
```

This will produce something like:

```
data = {"a": 1, "b": 2, ...};
```

This is already a decoded object.  You can't then `json_decode` it again. And there's no need to do so.  If you insist on `json_decode`ing it, then you need to output it as a string:

```
data = "<?= str_replace("\"", "\\\"", json_encode($arr)) ?>";
```

This will produce something like this:

```
data = "{\"a\": 1, \"b\": 2, ...}";
```

Now your `data` contains a string, which can be `json_decode`d.

Comment: The JSON-encoded object will have double-quotes around the object keys.

Comment: @cdmckay Yes, I think you're right, I'll update the answer.  However in this case it makes no difference.

Comment: semicolons in JS are optitional

Comment: @krabats: That's not always true: http://blog.magnetiq.com/post/493356934/when-semicolons-are-not-optional-in-javascript

Comment: @cdmckay you're right about that one but most of the time its handy I dont have to write them